# Referencing an equation from a different chapter of the same document with tex4ht

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, tex4ht

I am trying to convert to HTML a big LaTeX document (book class) subdivided into several chapters. I am using tex4ht. My problem is that, if I choose to export each chapter as separate pages, when I reference an equation from a different chapter, I get ??? instead of the equation number. The following snippet illustrates this issue.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\begin{equation}
  1+1=2
  \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\chapter{Second}
Reference to first chapter's equation: $\ref{eq1}$.
\begin{equation}
  2+2=4
  \label{eq2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If I convert this file (snippet.tex) to HTML using `make4ht --utf8 snippet.tex "mathlm,mathjax"`, then it works fine. I get the following:

[image]

However, if I use `make4ht --utf8 snippet.tex "mathlm,mathjax,2"` instead, the page corresponding to chapter 2 looks like that:

[image]

Notice also that, in this second case, the equation number is now 1, which means that there are two equations 1 within the same document. I have tried to add the chapter number in the equation number, by adding `\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}` in the preamble of my TeX file, but it has no effect.

Comment: I think you use a wrong option: it should be `mathml` instead of `mathlm`. You use pure MathJax now, which means that references to equations don't work correctly.

Comment: Indeed, that was a stupid mistake. Thank you very much for your help.